# How to bind name with object --> param value? AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am making app using Twitch api and i am on the stage to represent different streams. I am using  in the view and passing stream-name from the $scope.streamName but the stream do not load.

Here is the controller:

```
app.controller('streamController', function($scope, $http, $location) {
var streamName = $location.path().substring(9).toLowerCase();
$http.jsonp('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/' + streamName + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.data = data;
    $scope.streamName = data.name;
    console.log(streamName);
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
});
```

and passing streamName to "object"

```
           <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="378" width="620" data="//www-cdn.jtvnw.net/swflibs/TwitchPlayer.swf" bgcolor="#000000">
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
                <param name="allowNetworking" value="all" />
                <param name="movie" value="//www-cdn.jtvnw.net/swflibs/TwitchPlayer.swf" />
                <param name="flashvars" value="channel={{streamName}}&auto_play=true&start_volume=100" />
            </object>
```

When i inspect the element in the browser everything is there but the stream window won't load. Any ideas why?

I tried it even without $http request but the result is the same....

This is example of the json i am getting from $http:
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/starladder1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `streamName` is not ready immediately when the page loads, even if you set it later, the `object` tag is not gonna change its contents.

You should make a directive for that object tag, pass the streamName as a reference to that directive, and when it changes you add the html of the embed object.

Your main html would look like this:

```
<twitch-video stream="streamName"></twitch-video>
```

And your directive would look like this:

```
app.directive('twitchVideo',[function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div></div>', // your container
    scope: {
      stream: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        scope.$watch(attrs.stream, function(value) {
           element.html(''); // clear any content
           if(value){
                element.html('your resulting object tag with the stream name received');
           }
        });
    }
  }
}]);
```